# how to get changes of ng2-smart-table event from user input not on setFilter, setPaging, setSort

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am using Akveo's [ng2 smart table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/) in my angular project.

I have done the following,

```
source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();

this.source.onChanged().subscribe((changes) => { //Trigering while user input in filter or paging or sorting
      if (includes(['filter', 'sort', 'page'], changes.action)) {
          getEnrolledServices();
      }
}

getEnrolledServices(){
    //API call goes here
    this.source.load(responce-data-from-api);
    this.setFilter(filter-object-from server); //This is trigering the Onchaged 
}
```

**Working of the above code**

onchnaged() is triggering while user input like a filter, sort, paging. And getEntrolledservices is method is called and received the data from API.

**issue and my requirement**

Here, SetFilter() in getEnrolledservices() method is again triggering the onchanged() and getEnrolledServicesmethod. I have to trigger onChanged() only on user input not on setFilter